# Reusing fragments in different perspectives

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I have a partstack I want to reuse in a different fragment.  It looks like I can import the part stack in one fragment, so I did this.
Then under my Part Sash Container, I add a PlaceHolder element and select this imported Part in the "reference" section.

On both plugins, I have org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model extended.

And yet, nothing shows up.

I also tried to simplify it by just importing one Part.  This also does not work.

I know I can create the entire structure and assign new IDs and reference the class files directly, but I don't think that is the correct way to accomplish this.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You put the element you want to share in the 'Shared Elements' section of the 'Trimmed Window' definition.

You then put 'Placeholder' entries in all the Perspectives that want to use the shared element.

Comment: Okay I only have my part stack in a ModelFragment->sharedElement(my.mainwindow), but it causes me not to be able to see it in the "Import" of my other Fragment.e4xmi.

Comment: This is not something I have ever tried to do. Googling for 'eclipse import shared element' gives some possible questions about this on the Eclipse forums.

Comment: I think the E4 tooling is not that smart: just create a new (MPart) import and manually enter the ID of your part. The framework will try to resolve all references after it has merged all fragments into the application model.